# How to make a dataframe from images python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database

I ran into a problem - to make a dataframe of images. I have a lot of folders, there are more folders in them, and then images. The whole point is that I don't understand how I can upload images to the pandas dataframe. I looked through many different options, not one did not fit. The layout of the images:

```
.../Volvo/V60/0.png, 1.png ... 101.png
```

I want to have a pandas dataframe or any other one to which it will be possible to read and take data with images from it. Example:

```
     Automaker     Model     Images
0    Volvo         V60       0.png
1    Volvo         V60       1.png
...
999  BMW           M4        302.png
```

At the same time, there should be no files other than df (csv).
Is it possible to implement this or something like this? I will be very glad to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to search for files like this.

Here's an example of how to recursively search the current directory for .png files.

```
from pathlib import Path
image_dir_path = '.'
print(Path(image_dir_path).rglob('*.png'))
```

Then, you just need to reformat that into a dataframe. Here's how to do that:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

image_dir_path = '.'
paths = [path.parts[-3:] for path in
         Path(image_dir_path).rglob('*.png')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=paths, columns=['Automaker', 'Model', 'Images'])
print(df)
```

Note: you'll probably need to change `image_dir_path` to the directory of images on your computer.

Comment: Thanks, it's cool, it solves part of the problem (although I've already been able to do that, but your code is much smaller). But to use it, you need to have files, and I need everything to be in one file (dataframe), is it possible to do this?

Comment: @svyatoslavs I don't understand the question. 1) You have image files already, yes? 2) Strictly speaking, the dataframe is not a file. It doesn't exist on disk. 3) When you say you want the images "in" the dataframe, what do you mean by that? What kinds of operations do you want to be able to do? I interpreted the question to mean that you wanted the filename of each image in the dataframe.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been explaining badly since childhood, but I'll try to explain. I have image files, but the bottom line is that the dataframe will be on the internet. And to reduce the space and easier distribution, I want to put everything in one file. That is, in addition to the dataframe, the user does not need the images themselves. I just have a big problem - the images weigh 100 GB and I want to do everything compactly and reduce the weight.

Comment: It is possible that I am no longer talking about a dataframe, but a dataset. Roughly and briefly speaking, I want df to have not the path itself, so to speak, but the images themselves. That is, you will not need to download images, you will only need a csv (data frame) file.

Comment: For example, can I convert images to numpy and put them in a dataframe? Then the images will be in it - in one file.

Comment: Using a dataframe in that way will have some disadvantages. One disadvantage is that anyone who wants to use your dataset will need a computer with 100 GB of memory to load the dataframe. Another is that CSV doesn't natively support images, so you'd have to encode them as text somehow. What about using a zip file?

Comment: It's a good idea, it's sad that you can't do everything in one file or somehow with numpy. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @PratishthaS I'd recommend you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that.